# Disable word wrap in Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 17.04

On Nautilus, when I create a folder and the title hits 10 characters, it wraps and the last part of the title is centred underneath.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxt4t.png).

Is there a way I can stop this from happening?

(**17.04**)